# Debugging in intellij without using the 'F' keys

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

im using intellij as my ide, when i try to debugg with intellij i need to use the 'f' keys in order to move to the next line, the problem is that my laptop f keys are embedded in windows functions , such as volume up, flight mode, mic off etc.
is there a way to debugg without using the 'f' keys?
thanks so much /

Comment: you can use your mouse for it in debugging window.

Comment: you can change the Keymap in the Settings or just use the FN key on your keyboard

Answer (score 1):

You can use your mouse to get into/skip into and other debugger option. Attached is the screen shot for the same.

Here Next to console , there are various options and you can use your mouse to control them.

[image]